# MySQL With Left Join and Sum - NULL value vs No Results

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT
    p.name, p.pid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (c.status!=2 and c.status !=7) OR c.status is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS incomplete,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.status=2 or c.status=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS complete
FROM 
    projects p
LEFT JOIN 
    components c ON p.pid = c.pid  
WHERE
    p.uid = 123456
GROUP BY 
    p.pid
```

and it works great.. EXCEPT.

In the components table the status can be `NULL`
and there are also situations where there are no rows from the component table for the matching `p.pid`

When the status is counted, it's counting both instances as the same.

**Is there a way to differentiate the column null value VS a no matching row null?**

Thanks

Comment: please add a description of your table. Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to distinguish the "missing" row vs a NULL value from a matching row.

We can check the two cases by referencing an expression (a column) that is *guaranteed* to be non-NULL when a matching row is found.

Given the join predicate:

```
p.pid = c.pid
```

we know a NULL value will never satisfy the equality condition, so we know that a matching row from `c` (the outer joined table) is guaranteed to have a `pid` value that is not null.

We can do a check of that column in an expression. For example, getting a count of rows from `p` where a matching row is missing. And changing the incomplete count to include only rows where a matching row was found

```
SELECT p.name
     , p.pid
     , SUM(CASE 
           WHEN c.pid IS NULL
-- #            -------------
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0 
           END
       ) AS cnt_missing
     , SUM(CASE 
           WHEN c.pid IS NOT NULL AND (c.status NOT IN (2,7) OR c.status IS NULL)
-- #           ---------------------
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0 
           END
       ) AS cnt_incomplete
     , SUM(CASE 
           WHEN c.status IN (2,7) 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0
           END
       ) AS cnt_complete
  FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually wrap the `SUM` in a `IFNULL` statement when you could have some null in the sum:

```
SELECT
    p.name, p.pid,
    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN (c.status!=2 and c.status !=7) OR c.status is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), 0) AS incomplete,
    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN c.status=2 or c.status=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), 0) AS complete
FROM 
    projects p
LEFT JOIN 
    components c ON p.pid = rc.pid  
WHERE
    p.uid = 123456
GROUP BY 
    p.pid
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no matching row in `components` then `c.pid` is `null` and this is what you must check **first**.

If this fails then check if `c.status` is `null` which means that there is a matching row but with null status.